# Unable to Display pdf in Android App on clicking

Tags: android

I am working on one Android Project.which have functionality of download the pdf through URL given by web services consumes  and Open pdf directly by clicking I am using the following Code

```
public void openPdf(int position) {

        if (!getActivity().isFinishing()) {
            /*Use if you Need to download the pdf*/
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(myData.get(position).getLink()), "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

but it is not opening and gives  error popup
 [Popup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkiHC.png)

Comment: Are you using device simulator? if yes, it should have any application which is accepting pdf format type to open. Otherwise it will not show any applications. Make sure to install PDF viewer application from play store and try again. It will show apps in the actionsheet to open.

Comment: I have pdf viewer in device.

Comment: I am testing directly on the device and it has a pdf viewer

Comment: Can I show me your Logcat? Right now this is more like an interrupted file error.

Comment: There is no interrupted file error